# Free GIF animator

Tags: gratis, animation, gif

I'm looking for a program that can produce an animated GIF from an image sequence. Something like [Ulead GIF Animator](http://ulead-gif-animator.en.softonic.com/), [GIF Movie Gear](http://www.gamani.com/) or [GIF Animator](http://www.gif-animator.com/) but with the following requirements;

- Must be free (open source would be perfect, but not required)
- No added water marks or text in the output GIF that marks that it was generated with a free/trial version of a product
- Doesn't expire
- Display time can be set for each image

Answer (score 14, accepted):

More recent than Microsoft GIF Animator: [Photoscape](http://www.photoscape.org/ps/main/index.php)

- free
- works on Windows
- no water mark
- no expiration
- display time can be set for each image:

[image]

Answer (score 11):

You can use [Microsoft GIF Animator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_GIF_Animator):

- free
- works on Windows (from Windows 95 to Windows 8)
- no water mark
- no expiration
- display time can be set for each image:

[image]

It's a pretty old application though.

Comment: I can confirm that it works with Windows 8, however, I have encountered some serious drawbacks such as loading errors caused by some *.gifs (which were created by MS Paint!) and display/render errors also caused by some *.gifs. All in all, that application is pretty outdated.

Comment: Thanks! Yes outdated but used to be widely used :)

Answer (score 10):

If you don't mind using the command line, [**gifsicle**](http://www.lcdf.org/gifsicle/) is one of the best GIF animators I know of.  It's open source (which means you get the full feature set for free, no watermarks or other tricks), and has a versatile and powerful command line interface than can be useful for batch operation.  It does take a few minutes to learn, but the [manual page](http://www.lcdf.org/gifsicle/man.html), and especially the "examples" section at the end, do a pretty good job of explaining it.

The best part of gifsicle, however, is that it's *very* good at optimizing GIF animations.  Even if you use some other tool to initially generate the animation, consider running them through gifsicle with the `-O3` switch afterwards — you may be surprised by how much it can shave off the file size.

---

If you'd prefer a graphical tool, the [**GIMP**](http://www.gimp.org/) image editor (basically, an open source Photoshop clone) can export GIF animations.  Since GIMP is a full-fledged image editor, you can even use it to create your animations from scratch if you want; see e.g. [this tutorial on creating GIF animations in GIMP](http://www.gimp.org/tutorials/Simple_Animations/).

Alternatively, if you already have a series of images that you want to turn into an animation, the trick is to open the images with *File → Open as Layers...*.  You can select multiple files in the dialog, and GIMP will open them as layers of the same image.  Then just follow the tutorial to animate them, or experiment with the animation tools found under *Filters → Animation*.
(Tip: You can adjust the time delay and disposal mode of each animation frame by [editing the name of the corresponding layer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/17482/gif-animation-skipping-immediately-to-last-frame/17537#17537).)

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Mobile Platform for Creating GIF, then there is an App called "GIFSmak" 
Playstore Url: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.smak.animatedcamera

- It is free
- No watermarking
- Works flawlessly on most of the Android devices
- Multiple Options for creating GIFs
- UI is very user friendly

Here are some Screenshots:
[image]
[image]

I hope this helps you and solves your problem :)

Answer (score 2):

http://ezgif.com/maker is one of the best web based GIF creators/editors.

- free and no watermarks
- great quality and sane file size/count limits
- display time can be set for each frame, as well as loop count
- many powerful features after GIF creation - optimization, color effects, crop/resize/rotate tools
- you can add or remove frames from existing gifs

[image]